# Error when installing composer using windows installer

Tags: php, composer-php

The Composer installer script did not run correctly because composer.phar was not downloaded.
when i try use `cmd` using `php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"` i dont get answer just show the place to write code again then i put

```
php -r "if (hash_file('SHA384', 'composer-setup.php') === 'aa96f26c2b67226a324c27919f1eb05f21c248b987e6195cad9690d5c1ff713d53020a02ac8c217dbf90a7eacc9d141d') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"
```

and i get as answer Warning: hash_file(composer-setup.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Command line code on line 1
Installer corrupt
Warning: unlink(composer-setup.php): No such file or directory in Command line code on line 1

Thank for help

Answer (score 2):

You should to remember if you added it to in your environment's `PATH` variable then you don't need to type `php composer.phar`. 
Otherwise, if it didn't work you should to install `composer.phar` .

Try to run this command :

```
php -r "eval('?>'.file_get_contents('http://getcomposer.org/installer'));"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the file manually through a browser at https://getcomposer.org/installer and saving it as composer-setup.php. Then make sure you run the second command (the one with hash-file) in the same directory as the file you just saved.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to install composer in Ubuntu

1. Get a key for composer here: https://getcomposer.org/installer
2. `php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"`
3. `php -r "if (hash_file('SHA384', 'composer-setup.php') === 'SET YOUR DOWNLOADED KEY') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"`
4. Then you got a installation path copy them and run a following command.
5. `sudo mv composer.phar **/usr/local/bin/composer** (Replace your installed path)`

Now enjoy with your composer